# Reading, modifying and writing a CSV with CSVHelper (variable scope with 'using' )

Tags: c#, scope, using, csvhelper

This is a general coding question of how I can share the same list of data between the stages of reading, modifying and writing.

I'm a novice and new to C# too, so I'm struggling. I was expecting to be able to: read the CSV into the variable `records`, modify one or more of the records and then write out the modified data as a new CSV, but there is a scope issue with the `using` function.

The code below won't compile because records is out of scope in both the `foreach` loop that aims to modify some data and again when I'm trying to write the modified file.

I have tried various things to make `records` a more global variable but they have all failed and I am out of my depth.

I'm not even sure that this is the best way to approach the problem, so any advice would be appreciated.

```
   private void Btn_Merge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Read the CSV into 'records'
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(textBox_Shopify.Text);
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Contact>();
        }

        // We now need to find the record for a specific person and change it
        foreach (Contact customer in records)
        {
            if (customer.Email == "john.dow@business.com")  // Hard-coded while testing
            {
                string Tags = customer.Tags;   // Get the current tags
                                               // If the Lead Marking tag is not already there, add it
                if (!Tags.Contains("Send me Lead Marketing"))
                {
                    // If there are tags already there, append a semi-colon separator
                    if (customer.Tags.Length > 0)
                    {
                        customer.Tags += ";";
                    }
                    customer.Tags += "Send me Lead Marketing";
                    MessageBox.Show(customer.Email + "  Tags: " + customer.Tags);  //Just while I'm testing

                }
            }
            // If the customer is not in the list, add them as a new record

            // To do...
        }

        // We can now write out the modified file
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\Output.csv"))
        using (var outputCSV = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            outputCSV.WriteRecords(records);
        }

    }

    public class Contact
    {
        [Name("First Name")]  // This 'attribute' allows the class property First_Name to be matched to the header "First Name"
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        [Name("Last Name")]
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Name("Accepts Email Marketing")]
        public string Accepts_Email_Marketing { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        [Name("Province Code")]
        public string Province_Code { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [Name("Country Code")]
        public string Country_Code { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Name("Accepts SMS Marketing")]
        public string Accepts_SMS_Marketing { get; set; }
        [Name("Total Spent")]
        public string Total_Spent { get; set; }
        [Name("Total Orders")]
        public string Total_Orders { get; set; }
        public string Tags { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        [Name("Tax Exempt")]
        public string Tax_Exempt { get; set; }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mureinik is halfway there.  Since CsvHelper will only [yield](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/) records as you iterate them, you will also need to call `ToList()` or in some other way iterate the records within the using statement.

```cs
IEnumerable<Contact> records;

// Read the CSV into 'records'
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(textBox_Shopify.Text);
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    records = csv.GetRecords<Contact>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define `records` in the scope of the entire method:

```cs
private void Btn_Merge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<Contact> records;

    // result of the code...
```

Comment: Many thanks to both of you as the combination of declaring 'records' at the head and then adding the .ToList() solved it for me.